# Download RSS feed that's behind a login with Java

Tags: soap-api

This may sound strange but...

I want to retrieve an RSS feed from my company's salesforce site. I want to do this using Java. Basically I need to login to the site using Java and then read the feed and display it on another site. I was trying to use the SOAP API but it seems it isn't designed to do what I want.

anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: How is the RSS exposed?

Comment: If the feed data isn't out of the box exposed through soap and rest APIs you could opt to expose it ourselve from apex web/rest services

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how it is exposed. I"ll try to explain the best way I know. It is generated as a visual force page. The page basically just displays the code for an RSS feed.